Как можно практиковать C/C++?
Если бы я знал Python, я бы писал Telegram-ботов или backend для сайтов. Если бы я знал Java, я бы писал плагины и моды для игры Minecraft. Я изучаю C/C++, что я могу сделать, зная C/C++? Для меня на С/C++ я вижу только:
Разработка операционных систем, инструменты для управления памятью и ресурсами, разработка игр, создание собственных игровых движков, программирование микроконтроллеров и встраиваемых систем, мультимедийное программирование, создание серверных приложений и сетевых протоколов.
Для меня эти вещи пока что кажутся большими проектами. В общем вопрос такой как практиковать С/C++.

А зачем вы вообще его начали изучать?

На C++ можно все делать как бы) Можно писать телеграмм ботов и бакенд для сайта.. если хочется..

Какая сфера вам близка? Напишите в ней что-то простоею Или найдите чей-нибудь проект на Гитхабе и поковыряйте его.

@HolyBlackCat я просто прохожу курс C/C++ и вот думаю что я потом в итоге буду писать, не бросать же изучение языка.

"не бросать же изучение языка" Если он вам нравится, или то что вы хотите писать обычно пишут на С++ - тогда не бросать. А если он вам никаким боком не нужен - тогда бросить и сэкономить время.

Я задавался таким же вопросом. Вот тебе несколько идей:

Напиши класс String без использования библиотеки string
Аналогично напиши класс Vector
Напиши интерпретатор языка BrainFuck
Напиши простой калькулятор на Qt5

